# Javascript object sorting

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, object

```
users[usernames] = {
    userName        : username,
    userId          : id,
    userStatuINT    : statu,
    userMobilemi    : mobile,
};
```

**Console log :**

```
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

**Output :**

```
{
  "Guest-77":
      {"userName":"Jack","userId":"l1YeHSMYWvqUNgPPpvxE","userStatuINT":9,"userMobilemi":false},
  "Guest-47":
      {"userName":"Carter","userId":"zsq3Qcpd9qGw3X6kpvxF","userStatuINT":0,"userMobilemi":false},
  "Guest-68":{
      {"userName":"Alex","userId":"jmstDvTTLhZCLRW7pvxG","userStatuINT":4,"userMobilemi":false} 
}
```

**While code :**

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
   // sorting...
});
```

Hello.
this data "userStatuINT" How do I sort?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have any data structures that express any kind or order there, so there isn't anything to sort (not unless you want to express the data in some other form at the same time).

Comment: What have you tried, can you show us any code? How do you want the data sorted?

Comment: **users[usernames] = {
    userName        : username,
    userId          : id,
    userStatuINT    : statu,
    userMobilemi    : mobile,
};**

Comment: @SemihVURAL You have an answer from Guffa now. How about you actually give it a try now? You haven't really shown any effort yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort properties in an object. Copy the data into an array and sort it.

Example:

```
var arr = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value){
  arr.push({ id: key, data: value });
});
arr.sort(function(x,y){
  var xn = x.data.userStatuINT;
  var yn = y.data.userStatuINT;
  return xn == yn ? 0 : xn < yn ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: `return x.data.userStatuINT - y.data.userStatuINT` is somewhat easier.

Comment: @IngoBürk: Yes, but it only works for numbers. Someone else might want to use the example for something related.

Comment: Guffa, my array : 

users[usernames] = {
    userName        : username,
    userId          : id,
    userStatuINT    : statu,
    userMobilemi    : mobile,
};

Comment: It works for booleans, too! :) Just kidding. If you want to keep it that generic, why not. Just wanted to point it out. There's nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: **ADD :** 

    `users[usernames] = {
        userName        : username,
        userId          : id,
        userStatuINT    : statu,
        userMobilemi    : mobile,
    };`

Comment: @SemihVURAL: The output in the console is for an object, not an array. Even if you created an array, you use it as an object, i.e. putting data in the properties instead of as array items. The actual array data is empty. You may need to change it to an actual object for the `each` method to iterate the object properties instead of the array items.