# Javascript Object Sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

**My data :**

```
books = {};

books[unique_id] = {
   name   : "Zimané Kurdi",
   author : "Leyla Z.",
   date   : "2013.12.12",
   y_no   : 5
}
```

**Output :**

```
$.each(books, function(key, value){
   // shorting "y_no"
});
```

How can I do? (shorting "y_no")

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Only an array has an actual sort order. Since `books` is an object, you can's sort it.

Comment: The link you gave me different from my code.

Comment: You're [duplicating your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293397/javascript-object-sorting)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're asking how you can sort, I wouldn't recommend using `Object.each`.  Instead, set yourself up with an array, and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) that:

```
books = [];

books[unique_id] = { // assuming unique_id is numeric, otherwise it won't be an array member
    name   : "Zimané Kurdi",
    author : "Leyla Z.",
    date   : "2013.12.12",
    y_no   : 5
};
// ... presumably adding more objects to books

function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.y_no < b.y_no) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a.y_no > b.y_no) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

books.sort(compare);
```